# HAProxy frontend backend continuously starting and stopping

Tags: haproxy

I am using an HAProxy **1.6.4** to load balance my traffic into different servers. As in now my haproxy runs inside a docker container. In my configuration i have different frontends and backends. As in my testing my frontend backends works and forwards traffic to my desired request.

But the problem is some of my traffic is getting CONN_RESET error. and by viewing haproxy logs i found that my fronends and backends are continously restarting. the log looks like this.

```
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping backend default-backend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping backend default-backend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping frontend http-frontend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping frontend http-frontend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping backend http-service-vbv7kk in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping backend http-service-vbv7kk in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:36 haproxy[32715]: Stopping backend http-service-tsah7b in 0 ms.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy default-backend started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy default-backend started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy http-frontend started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy http-frontend started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy http-service-vbv7kk started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy http-service-vbv7kk started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy http-service-orry6w started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy tcp-frontend-key-3443 started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy tcp-service-bzczrg started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy tcp-service-hacbno started.
local0.notice: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32720]: Proxy tcp-service-hacbno started.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping backend default-backend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping backend default-backend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping frontend http-frontend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping frontend http-frontend in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping backend http-service-tsah7b in 0 ms.
local0.warn: Apr 15 12:30:37 haproxy[32719]: Stopping backend http-service-tsah7b in 0 ms
```

the simplest configuration i had looked like [this](http://codepad.org/FjcyTvb4).

Now my question is what am i missing? why my connection gets reseted and why the restarting?

*Question asked in ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/770611/haproxy-frontend-backend-continuously-starting-and-stopping) but looks like nobody is checking.

Comment: Any progress on this?